# NoneType in a xml parsing but there is a message

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I get the next xml response in a webservice:

```xml
<error>failed to communicate with device</error>
```

And I want to save the error message, so I do the next (I do it in others situations and work but not in this case):

```py
[...]
if tree.tag == 'error':
    mensaje = tree.find('error')
    print('The error is: '+mensaje)
```

And I get `None`. If I put `mensaje = tree.find('error').text` I get a error because `NoneType` has no attribute text.

Why can't I get the error message?

Thanks

Comment: If the condition 'tree.tag == "error"' evaluates to True you should be able to simply 'print(tree.text)' since that already is the error element of your xml, right?

Comment: @meissner_ is correct; `tree` is already `error`. If you do `tree.find('error')`, you're trying to find a child `error` and `error` doesn't have any child elements.